# Using Alexa Capabilities within an Alexa skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Alexa is able to find service providers and also call them.  Is it possible to use this capability from an Alexa skill. For example could an Alexa skill find and call a near-by doctor upon request?

Answer (score 1):

The direct calling and search features of Alexa are not available currently within a custom skill, however you could achieve this your by using 3rd party APIs.

For example you can look up local businesses using the Yelp API and connect and connect a call using a Twilio API. You may want to register the user’s mobile number for this particular example.

It should also be noted that the features available in the Amazon SDK are always being updated. So it may be added in the future.